# Odoo-Creation sequence based on PostgreSQL sequence

Tags: postgresql, odoo, sequence

I am working with odoo 14 and I want to customize sale.order number generation. So, I want to create new sequence (ir.sequence) based on PostgreSQL database sequence object.

Do you have any idea?

Thank you for your help.

SAAD

Comment: Could you please explain about your requirement. Sale module already has its code to generate a sequence for sale order by default. If you need to create a sequence using postgresql  then you may checkout the link given below https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/databases/postgresql/sequence/#:~:text=Sequences%20in%20PostgreSQL%20are%20very,all%20our%20web%20hosting%20plans.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, I want to use the same postgresql sequence by odoo and by another e-commerce application.
For example, when I create the first sale order by odoo, I get C00001, and when I create the sale order by my e-commerce application I get C00002, etc.

Comment: Do you want to integrate odoo and other ecommerce app?

Comment: Yes. I am working on a connector between odoo and other e-commerce app.

Comment: You have your generated sequence in odoo as first like C00001. If it is generated then only you have to generate a sequence in other ecommerce app as like C00002 after integrating it. Am i getting your point?

Answer (score 0):

from odoo import api, fields, models
import psycopg2

class ventes(models.Model):
_inherit = ['sale.order']

```
company = fields.Char()

name = fields.Char(string='Order Reference')

#Connection a la base de donnees
def open_conn(self):
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user="user",
                                      password="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                      host="192.168.1.1",
                                      port="5432",
                                      database="ventes")

        print("Using Python variable in PostgreSQL select Query")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        postgreSQL_select_Query = "select nextval('myOdoo')"

        cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        return  row[0]

    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print("Error fetching data from PostgreSQL table", error)

    finally:
        # closing database connection
        if connection:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("PostgreSQL connection is closed \n")

@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    num = self.open_conn()
    vals['name'] = num
    result = super(ventes, self).create(vals)
    return result
```